# C++ How to alert an user like messagebox in linux

Tags: c++

Hi guys, I am currently running Ubuntu by VMware player using C++ code.

Basically I got this code that counts down 600 seconds. When it reaches 0 it's supposed to alert the user with an alert box saying:

`"Times up!"`

I know Linux doesn't have messageBox, I saw a suggestion for using QT but I don't want to use QT. Can I show an alert in any form like in linux command or something?

What suggestions might you guys have for a message box similar to a message box kind of alert.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 4):

Zenity could be what you're looking for; it's a program (rather than a toolkit) which you could use like this to produce a messagebox:

```
zenity --info --text="This is an information box."
```

Edit: zenity will create similar dialogs like `MessageBox` does, but they are more rarely used on Ubuntu these days (compared to `notify-send` notifications).

Comment: This is ugly, and zenity is not availiably on all distributions anymore.

Comment: @drahnr, *ugly* would not be the word I'd use but yes, there are downsides to this approach.

Comment: There is no reason to use it anymore, pretty much _every_ linux OS has the notification deamon running, which does not steal the focus of your current application - which zenity does.

Comment: @drahnr, while your suggestion is better for many purposes (upvoted it for that), it also depends on what OP is looking for. `zenity` will create an "alert-like box" if that's what he wants for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

This will create a popup message in the tray

```
notify-send ["title"] "message"
```

Another - ugly and deprecated - option would be to use `zenity`, but I do not encourage you to do so.